# Como trabalhar com dados binários

Tags: c, decimal, hexadecimal, binary, ansi

Tenho uma função em C que recebe dois bytes um com maior valor significativo (msb) e outro com menor (lsb) e depois os converte para decimal.

```
int get_pea(char *buffer)
{
    char lsb[8], msb[8], pea[16];
    unsigned int i;

    convertDecimalBinary((int) buffer[0], lsb, 8);
    convertDecimalBinary((int) buffer[1], msb, 8);

    for (i=0; i<8; i++) {
        pea[i] = msb[i];
    }

    for (i=0; i<8; i++) {
        pea[i+8] = lsb[i];
    }

    return convertBinaryDecimal(pea, 16);
}
```

Essa função esta bem burrinha com tantas conversões de tipo, sei que no C não há necessidade de fazer tanta coisa assim, mas não vi outra forma para:

```
buffer[0] = 0x84;
buffer[1] = 0x03;
```

Tendo esses dois bytes como eu converto para decimal o 0x03 0x84 ?

Comment: Só uma dúvida, por que `pea`? Alguma relação com ervilhas?

Comment: 0x03 é um número. Se você só precisa da representação decimal é só usar o `%d` da família de funções `printf`. O mesmo para 0x84. Estar em hexa, binário ou decimal é apenas forma de representação. O número em sua essência existe por si só, não necessita de mais nada. Se você quer juntar os dois bytes considerando que `buffer[0]` é o low-byte é que o `buffer[1]` é o high-byte de uma palavra de 16 bits little-endian, bastaria fazer o shift bitwise do high-byte em 8 casas e juntar com o low-byte: `(buffer[0] & 0xff) | ((buffer[1] & 0xff) >> 8)`

Answer (score 1):

O comentário fornecido pelo Jefferson Quesado talvez seja mais eficiente, entretanto eu considero:

```
#include <stdint.h>    

uint16_t binary2decimal(const char buffer[2])
{
    union {
        char bytes[2];
        uint16_t value;
    } endianess;
    endianess[0] = buffer[0]; /*msb*/
    endianess[1] = buffer[1]; /*lsb*/

    return endianess.value;
}
```

mais amigável para o leitor. Embora este código funcione em um x86 (little endian), este não funcionará em processadores big endian (como o ppc). Para mais detalhes, estude o funcionamento de unions em C.

Answer (score 0):

```
void get_pea(char *buffer)
    {
        char lsb = buffer[0];
        char msb = buffer[1];
        int mb;

    // Modo1 (@Jefferson Quesado)
        mb = (msb << 8) | (lsb << 0);
        printf("mb 0x%x or %d\n", mb, mb);

    // Modo 2 (@MrParrot)
        union {
            char bytes[2];
            uint16_t value;
        } uniteste;

        uniteste.bytes[0] = lsb;
        uniteste.bytes[1] = msb;

        printf("=> 0x%x or %d\n", uniteste.value, uniteste.value);

    }
```

Esse exemplo poderia ficar mais otimizado usando os tipos de stdint.h, obrigado a todos.